# Hadoop job tracker and task tracker not running on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, hadoop

I have installed hadoop .20 on my ubuntu 13.10 machine.
When I do start-all.sh only name node , data node and secondary node process starts, Job tracker and task tracker doesn't show.

I have used the installation instructions from
[here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).

Following is the log for job tracker

```
2014-03-24 12:46:42,860 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: java.lang.RuntimeException: Not a host:port pair: local
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.getAddress(JobTracker.java:2434)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.<init>(JobTracker.java:2050)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.startTracker(JobTracker.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.main(JobTracker.java:4799)
```

Comment: Lookd like this is a configuration issue. Can you post your `mapred-site.xml` file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
 <name>mapred.job.tarcker</name>
 <value>localhost:9001</value>
</property>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `mapred.job.tarcker` to `mapred.job.tracker`